# Most efficient way to convert 6 V to 5.5 V

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, linear

My goal is to design a USB charger for my phone/tablet when I don't have access to the power grid.  I've used a LM317 with a 12 V, 5 A·h SLA battery but it does not provide enough capacity due to the power dissipation of LM317:

$$(12~\mathrm{V} - 5.5~\mathrm{V}) \times 700~\mathrm{mA} = 4.55~\mathrm{W} \approx 5~\mathrm{W}$$

The LM317 burns about 5 W as heat.

I need to convert 6 V from my battery to around 5.5–5.6 V (AC USB charger voltage at 500 mA load) to charge more efficiently and decrease battery weight (half the cells, half the weight).

I've tried designing a op-amp regulator with a MOSFET but the V<sub>GS</sub> threshold is just too high for the op-amp to turn it on—it takes a V<sub>CC</sub> of about 8 V which starts to increase my heat losses to unacceptable levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "best" you mean "most efficient", then you want a [switched-mode power supply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply), or more specifically, a [buck converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter). Efficiencies above 70% are common, and above 90% is possible with careful design and selection.

With such a device, you may indeed be able to use a 12V battery without any more loss than you would have with a 6V battery.

The LM317 is a pass transistor driven by an error amplifier, essentially an op-amp plus a transistor. An op-amp plus a MOSFET is not very different, and you will not improve on the efficiency of an LM317 with any combination of op-amps and MOSFETS that don't involve rapid switching, and probably an inductor. Without switching, you have a [linear regulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regulator), and the only place excess voltage can go is into heat.

Electrical power is the product of current and voltage:

$$ P = IE $$

and as long as you have any device with a voltage across it and current flowing through it, you are converting electrical energy into something else, usually heat. Non-linear regulators avoid this problem by rapidly switching between periods of high voltage and low current, and low voltage and high current, except in an energy storage device (an inductor) which can store the electrical energy in something more easily recovered than heat (a magnetic field).

Comment: Yeah, by saying "best" I meant most-efficient. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Anyways I will need to get low Vgs MOSFET for this task.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. I said I connected OPAmp OUTPUT to the MOSFET's GATE and OPAmp's V- to the output voltage, V+ to the Zener diode (5.6V)

Comment: @BartekSzablowski it doesn't really matter what you've connected. Op-amps as MOSFETS (in any configuration likely to be called a "regulator") are linear devices. If you don't have some rapid switching (thus, no longer linear) and an inductor, the only way you can reduce the input voltage to the output voltage is by making heat, at the rate of \$ (V_{in}-V_{out}) \cdot I \$ (in watts).

Comment: Alright, so the only way of doing that is designing a Buck converter ? (Not gonna be that easy. Haha)

Comment: @BartekSzablowski you can buy them, also. Check ebay if cheap and low volume is your driving concern.

Comment: @BartekSzablowski there's *rarely* a good reason to "design" a SMPS, buy a controller (virtually everyone makes them nowadays) and season to taste with passives mentioned in the datasheet/app-notes.

Comment: FYI an LDO would probably be more efficient in this application because the voltage drop between battery and load are so small.  You would probably see about 75% to 95% efficiency depending on the Bat voltage.  Component count and complexity would be less too.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use an LDO: a "low drop-out" regulator. Low drop out means that the output voltage can be closer to the input voltage than in traditional regulators that can require several volts of drop out. There are many, many LDO's on the market, with different specs. They can be fixed voltage or adjustable. Perhaps there is one that puts out 5.5 or 5.6V, with a low enough drop-out that the input can be as low as 5.95V, and with enough current delivery.

Comment: You can "hack" a 5V LDO with a forward biased diode in its common path for 5.6V

Comment: The USB spec is 5 V±5%.  I don't know why 5.6V is the goal.  An LDO would work well over the input voltage range if the output is regulated down to 5.0V.

Comment: I also thought USB is really only 5V but it's not in some cases. For example; HTC's AC charger supplies 5.6V at 800mA load, and it's not broken since I have also tested other chargers of HTC and they all have very similar specs.

Answer (score 2):

A series diode. The voltage drop will be about 0.6V almost regardless the current through it. If that voltage drop is too much replace it with a Schottky diode, that will do about 0.3-0.4V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQEWwR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a good idea. Though the battery has it's state of charge and I want the voltage to be fairly stable over 100%-40% charge. (6.35V-5.95V)

Comment: You should add that requirement to your question.

Comment: I clearly said that I need to convert "battery voltage" so I thought it was pretty obvious.

Comment: This is probably going to be the most efficient way to drop 0.6V.  0.3W lost out of ~2.75 delivered.  If your input range is between 6.35V and 5.95V you won't maintain the USB spec range (1.0 to 2.0 spec) 5.25 V to 4.75 V.  With USB 3 it is 4.45–5.25 V.  But it still might be close enough to work.  A LDO set to 5.0V is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the LM2679 simple switcher series (now sold by Texas Instruments). You can get them in an adjustable version and they really are simple to implement; almost as simple as the LM317, but in a switchmode device. Parts count is very low too, for a switching regulator and the performance is very good.

from the data sheet: The LM2679 is part of the SIMPLE SWITCHER ® family of power converters. A complete design uses a minimum number of external components, which have been pre-determined from a variety of manufacturers. Using either this data sheet or a design software program called LM267X Made Simple (version 2.0) a complete switching power supply can be designed quickly. The software is provided free of charge and can be downloaded from Texas Instruments Internet site located at http://www.ti.com

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2679.pdf